# Define derivatives of symbols

Tags: symbolic, calculus-and-analysis, upvalues

I have a symbol `a` appearing in my computations, which has a complicated definition in terms of other variables. However, I know that any derivative of `a` has the form

```
da/dx = a^3 f(x)
```

for some known function `f`, and I would like to teach Mathematica how to do it.

I thought setting up-values would be appropriate, but I just can't get it right. My first attempt was

```
D[a, x_] ^:= a^3*f[x]
```

It works if I try `D[a, x5]` and gives `a^3*f[x5]`, but already `D[a^2, x5]` gives `0`. Then I thought it might help to actually define `a` as a function, so that Mathematica knows it has to compute derivatives of it too, so I tried

```
D[a[x1, x2], x_] ^:= a[x1, x2] f[x]
```

Again, the basic test passed and calling `D[a[x1, x2], x1]` gives what I want. However, calling `D[a[x1, x2]^2, x1]` gives `2 a[x1,x2]^2 Derivative[1,0][a][x1,x2]]`, I don't fully understand why Mathematica does that and doesn't just use the definition of `D` that is already there, but my last hope was to define this as an up-value too. However, setting this as an up-value for `a` doesn't work because the nesting is too deep, and the only way is to really set it as an up-value for `Derivative`, which already I think is not very good style. I was a bit surprised that `Derivative` was not a protected symbol, so I could just write

```
Derivative /: Derivative[1, 0][a][x1_, x2_] := D[a[x1, x2], x1]
Derivative /: Derivative[0, 1][a][x1_, x2_] := D[a[x1, x2], x2]
```

This passed the few simple test that I did, but I'm not happy with it. The biggest problem is that I have to specify all the dependencies of `a` explicitly and then make an individual definition of `Derivative` for each of them. Also the solution above doesn't look very clean, and I'm afraid that there will be some cases which I haven't thought of, where this doesn't work again. I would love to not specify the arguments of `a` and write something like `a[_]` or `a[__]`, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm a bit sad I wasn't able to solve this, given that what I want is so simple: to tell Mathematica, look, whenever you compute derivatives of an expression which contains `a`s with respect to some `x`, then derivative of each occurrence of `a` is `a^3 f(x)`.

Comment: Try your first approach but with the total derivative `Dt` instead.

Comment: @swish thanks, it seems to work. However, now any other symbol `b` that appears in the expression becomes `Dt[b,x]`, such that now I have to know which other symbols there will be beforehand and set `Dt[b,x]^:=0` for all possible `b`. Also in terms of performance, is there any difference between `D` and `Dt`?

Answer (score 5):

You want the `NonConstants` option to `D`.

```
D[a, x_, OptionsPattern[]] ^:= a^3*f[x]

D[a, x5]
(* a^3 f[x5] *)

D[a^2, x5, NonConstants -> a]
(* 2 a^4 f[x5] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think giving `a` a hidden dependence on `x` will cause difficulties. I would make it explicit, and do something like:

```
Derivative[1][a] = a[#]^3 f[#]&;
```

Then:

```
D[a[x], x]
D[a[x]^2, x]
D[g[a[x]], {x, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> a[x]^3 f[x]
>
> 2 a[x]^4 f[x]
>
> $\left(a(x)^3 f'(x)+3 a(x)^5 f(x)^2\right) g'(a(x))+a(x)^6 f(x)^2 g''(a(x))$

Answer (score 0):

According to the original post, `a`:"[h]as a complicated definition in terms of other variables". Also, the derivative of the symbol `a` *wrt* to variable `x` is equal to:`a^3f[x]`.

These two facts about symbol `a` have implications for the derivatives of `a`. This can be summarized by:

```
d[n_, x_, y___]:=Nest[D[#, x]/.D_[1, B___][a][X_, Y___]:>a[X,Y]^3f[X]&,a[x, y], n]
```

Effectively what 'function' `d` does is to recursively apply the definition of the derivative of `a` and return the result.

Having this auxiliary function at hand can be helpful in producing the derivatives of `a` for arbitrary order. Eg.

```
In[1]:= d[5, x]
```

produces $a(x)^3 f^{(4)}(x)+15 a(x)^5 f(x) f^{(3)}(x)+150 a(x)^7 f(x)^2 f''(x)+1050 a(x)^9 f(x)^3 f'(x)+225 a(x)^7 f(x) f'(x)^2+30 a(x)^5 f'(x) f''(x)+945 a(x)^{11} f(x)^5$

Finally, doing

```
Derivative[1, b___][a][x_, y___] := a[x, y]^3 f[x]
Derivative[n_, b___][a][x_, y___] := d[n, x, y]
```

yields a possible solution to the original problem

$_{(Ithink  Carl  Woll's  solution  is  more  elegant)}$